# Using a Case statement to update another table

Tags: sql-server, case, using

I have a table with one record in it. I need to update 8 fields in another table based on the TYPE column of the one record. I thought a Case statement was the way to go, but I am pulling my hare out! I have searched and seen some examples that come close BUT not quite! any help please! here is my code.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[PART_DIMENSION]

SELECT [SELL_PACK],
    CASE q.PACK_TYPE WHEN 'SELL' then 1,
              [SELL_PACK_UOM] = Q.PACK_ASSMBY,
              [SELL_PACK_QTY] = Q.QTY,
              [SELL_PACK_LENGTH] = Q.LENGTH,
              [SELL_PACK_WIDTH] = Q.WIDTH,
              [SELL_PACK_HEIGHT] = Q.HEIGHT,
              [SELL_PACK_WEIGHT] = Q.WEIGHT,
              [SELL_PACK_INNER_QTY] = Q.INNER_QTY,
              [SELL_PACK_CAN_NEST] = Q.CAN_NEST,
              [SELL_PACK_NEED_RETAIL_PACK] = Q.NEED_RETAIL_PACK
            FROM PART_DIMENSION as a
            INNER JOIN Qubiscan as q
            on a.part_id=q.part_id

    WHEN q.PACK_TYPE='INNER' then
           SET[INNER_PACK]  = 1,
              [INNER_PACK_UOM] = Q.PACK_ASSMBY,
              [INNER_PACK_QTY] = Q.QTY,
              [INNER_PACK_LENGTH] = Q.LENGTH,
              [INNER_PACK_WIDTH] = Q.WIDTH,
              [INNER_PACK_HEIGHT] = Q.HEIGHT,
              [INNER_PACK_WEIGHT] = Q.WEIGHT
            FROM PART_DIMENSION as a
            INNER JOIN Qubiscan as q
            on a.part_id=q.part_id

    WHEN q.PACK_TYPE='MASTER' then
           SET[MASTER_PACK] = 1,
              [MASTER_PACK_UOM] = Q.PACK_ASSMBY,
              [MASTER_PACK_QTY] = Q.QTY,
              [MASTER_PACK_LENGTH] = Q.LENGTH,
              [MASTER_PACK_WIDTH] = Q.WIDTH,
              [MASTER_PACK_HEIGHT] = Q.HEIGHT,
              [MASTER_PACK_WEIGHT] = Q.WEIGHT
            FROM PART_DIMENSION as a
            INNER JOIN Qubiscan as q
            on a.part_id=q.part_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting everything done in one shot is a good goal, but sometimes you can try to do too much at once. The CASE may not be the best choice in this circumstance, because doing what you want would really require about 24 CASE statements...doable, but I'm not sure how readable it would be. I'd suggest breaking this down into some simpler chunks first..consider this (hopefully with minimal typos :) ):

```
Update a
  from part_dimension a
  join qubiscan q
    on a.part_id=q.part_id
   set           a.[MASTER_PACK] = 1,
              a.[MASTER_PACK_UOM] = Q.PACK_ASSMBY,
              a.[MASTER_PACK_QTY] = Q.QTY,
              a.[MASTER_PACK_LENGTH] = Q.LENGTH,
              a.[MASTER_PACK_WIDTH] = Q.WIDTH,
              a.[MASTER_PACK_HEIGHT] = Q.HEIGHT,
              a.[MASTER_PACK_WEIGHT] = Q.WEIGHT
where q.pack_type='MASTER'
```

Repeat this block for the other two field lists/pack_types.

Comment: Great David! I had to move the FROM and JOIN to after the SET but I works well! And is much simpler that what I had originally envisioned. Thanks to Nepali Rookie as well. I did not use his solution, but I am sure it would have worked just as well!

Comment: You're welcome!! Should have realized myself I put the SET in the wrong place - that's what I get for putting something in my head without actually *thinking* it all the way through LOL. Glad to have been able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for a `SQL Server` version of the join in update statement,  you can split the update into three different statements and do something like this:

```
--SELL
UPDATE p1
SET p1.[SELL_PACK] = 1
    ,p1.[SELL_PACK_UOM] = Q.PACK_ASSMBY
    ,p1.[SELL_PACK_QTY] = Q.QTY
    ,p1.[SELL_PACK_LENGTH] = Q.[LENGTH]
    ,p1.[SELL_PACK_WIDTH] = Q.WIDTH
    ,p1.[SELL_PACK_HEIGHT] = Q.HEIGHT
    ,p1.[SELL_PACK_WEIGHT] = Q.[WEIGHT]
    ,p1.[SELL_PACK_INNER_QTY] = Q.INNER_QTY
    ,p1.[SELL_PACK_CAN_NEST] = Q.CAN_NEST
    ,p1.[SELL_PACK_NEED_RETAIL_PACK] = Q.NEED_RETAIL_PACK
FROM [dbo].[PART_DIMENSION] p1
INNER JOIN Qubiscan AS q ON p1.part_id = q.part_id
WHERE q.pack_type = 'SELL';

--INNER
UPDATE p2
SET p2.[INNER_PACK] = 1
    ,p2.[INNER_PACK_UOM] = Q.PACK_ASSMBY
    ,p2.[INNER_PACK_QTY] = Q.QTY
    ,p2.[INNER_PACK_LENGTH] = Q.[LENGTH]
    ,p2.[INNER_PACK_WIDTH] = Q.WIDTH
    ,p2.[INNER_PACK_HEIGHT] = Q.HEIGHT
    ,p2.[INNER_PACK_WEIGHT] = Q.[WEIGHT]
FROM [dbo].[PART_DIMENSION] p2
INNER JOIN Qubiscan AS q ON p2.part_id = q.part_id
WHERE q.pack_type = 'INNER';

--MASTER
UPDATE p3
SET p3.[MASTER_PACK] = 1
    ,p3.[MASTER_PACK_UOM] = Q.PACK_ASSMBY
    ,p3.[MASTER_PACK_QTY] = Q.QTY
    ,p3.[MASTER_PACK_LENGTH] = Q.[LENGTH]
    ,p3.[MASTER_PACK_WIDTH] = Q.WIDTH
    ,p3.[MASTER_PACK_HEIGHT] = Q.HEIGHT
    ,p3.[MASTER_PACK_WEIGHT] = Q.[WEIGHT]
FROM [dbo].[PART_DIMENSION] p3
INNER JOIN Qubiscan AS q ON p3.part_id = q.part_id
WHERE q.pack_type = 'MASTER';
```

Hope this helps!